# Can not identify the cause of Application crash

Tags: java, android

I have this following class which when runs and comes to a certain line in the class the application crashes. If i comment out that line the application runs well. When i look at the logcat i don't find any CausedBy Text. So can not figure out the cause of this crash. Someone please help me out to solve this.

```
public class Secondscreen extends Activity {


int total=0;
final ArrayList<Listitem> arrayList=new ArrayList<Listitem>();
BaseAdapter adapter =null;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen); 
ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


final TextView showtotal    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalprice);


final Button thirdBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.third);


final Controller aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

final int cartSize = aController.getCart().getCartSize();


//Addition of item to arraylist

if(cartSize >0)
    {   


        for(int i=0;i<cartSize;i++)
        {

           String pName   = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductName();
           int pPrice      = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductPrice();
           int pQuantity      = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductQuantity();
           String pDisc       = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductDesc();
           total = total + pPrice;

            Listitem item=new Listitem(pName, pPrice, pDisc, pQuantity);
            Log.e("quantity", ""+pQuantity);
            Log.e("Intem's quantity", ""+item.getQuantity());
            arrayList.add(item);
            Log.e("Arraylist item quantity", ""+arrayList.get(i).getQuantity());

        }
        showtotal.setText(""+total);

    }


         adapter= new BaseAdapter(){

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
                if (view == null) {
                    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pattern, null);
                }
                TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameview);
                TextView tv2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdesc);
                TextView tv3=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceView);
                TextView tv4=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantityView);
                Button btn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.patternButton);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int tempstore=arrayList.get(position).getPrice();


                        total=total-tempstore;
                        arrayList.remove(position);

                        showtotal.setText(""+total);

                        ModelProducts tempProductObject = aController.getProducts(position);

                        aController.getCart().removeProducts(tempProductObject);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        int cartSize2 = aController.getCart().getCartSize();


                    }

                });


                tv.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
                tv2.setText(""+arrayList.get(position).getPrice());                    
                tv3.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDesc());
                tv4.setText(arrayList.get(position).getQuantity()); //<-this is the line which when gets executed causes the application to crash.


                return view;
            }       

        };            
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);





   }
}
```

Comment: what does `getQuantity()` return an int value??

Comment: yes getQuantity() returns an int value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yes getQuantity() returns an int value

So change this

```
tv4.setText(arrayList.get(position).getQuantity());
```

to

```
tv4.setText(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getQuantity()));
```

What happens is `setText(int)` looks for a Resource with the int value if not found you end up getting `ResourceNotFoundException`

What you want is `setText(CharacterSequence)` so you need use `String.valueof(intvalue)`